# "handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101" message on terminal

Tags: networking, 20.04, ssl

From this morning, I'm seeing occasional error message like this on the terminal.

> [2023256:2023260:0701/133956.833008:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)]
> handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101

I couldn't find any information about this on the net. What does this error imply?
(ubuntu 20.04)